# Plotting three sets of points

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot 3 sets of points. For example consider

```
Xfinal={{79.7752, -4.5745}, {79.7752, -4.57458}, {79.7751, -4.57453},
{79.8622, -4.36018}, {79.8621, -4.36023}, {79.8623, -4.36031},
{79.5962, -4.39891}, {79.5962, -4.39893}, {79.5962, -4.3989}}
```

I am making it into three sets:

```
Xfinala = Xfinal[[1 ;; 3, All]]
Xfinalb = Xfinal[[4 ;; 6, All]]
Xfinalc = Xfinal[[7 ;; 9, All]]
```

I am using the following commands to plot:

```
Plotx = ListPlot[Xfinala, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
Ploty = ListPlot[Xfinalb, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Green}]
Plotz = ListPlot[Xfinalc, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
Plot1 = Show[Plotx, Ploty, Plotz]
```

Further, let

```
βa={-157.767, 1.42204, -9.90731} 
βb={-649.437, 7.96711, -3.24825}
```

Now I am trying to plot the following lines together with points using the following codes:

```
Plotsvma = 
 Plot[-(1/βa[[2]])*(βa[[2]]*x + βa[[1]]) , {x, -10, 10}]
Plotsvmb = 
 Plot[-(1/βb[[3]])*(βb[[2]]*x + βb[[1]]) , {x, -10, 10}]
```

and finally:

```
Plotx = Show[Plot1, Plotsvma , Plotsvmb ]
```

But it is not displaying all the plots... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: add `PlotRange->All` to `Show` .

Comment: Note that the because of very different scales in `Plot`s and `ListPlot`s all three points overlap in the output of `Show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, your problem is the incompatible [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) of the plots you are trying to [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html), that you can fix by hand or with `PlotRange->All` in `Show` as suggested by @kglr, while I was typing this answer.

I would do other things differently as well.

```
Xfinal = {{79.7752, -4.5745}, {79.7752, -4.57458}, {79.7751, \
-4.57453}, {79.8622, -4.36018}, {79.8621, -4.36023}, {79.8623, \
-4.36031}, {79.5962, -4.39891}, {79.5962, -4.39893}, {79.5962, \
-4.3989}}
```

Do a single [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) using [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) and [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) to avoid repeating code.

```
plot1 = ListPlot[
   Partition[Xfinal, 3]
   , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
   , PlotStyle -> Thread@{PointSize[Large], {Red, Green, Blue}}
   ];
```

Limit the use of global variables, using limited scope functions such as [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html)

```
plotsvm = With[
   {
    βa = {-157.767, 1.42204, -9.90731},
    βb = {-649.437, 7.96711, -3.24825}
    },
   Plot[
    {
     -(1/βa[[2]])*(βa[[2]]*x + βa[[1]]),
     -(1/βb[[3]])*(βb[[2]]*x + βb[[1]])
     }
    , {x, 75, 95}
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
    , FrameTicks -> True
    ]];


Show[plotsvm, plot1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi, This is good. I reccomend a small change {x, (Min /@ Transpose[Xfinal])[[2]], (Max /@ Transpose[Xfinal])[[1]]} instead of {x, 75, 95}.